# Field jdbcTemplate in SpringBootApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, jdbctemplate

I am following https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/ so in my main class I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class SpringGuideApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringGuideApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGuideApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("Creating tables");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE clients IF EXISTS");
    }
}
```

and at this point I receive error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jdbcTemplate in com.example.spring_guide.SpringGuideApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I understand error but to create `@Bean JdbcTemplate` I need to use:

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

but I don't want, I don't want any `dataSource` file I would like to have just in memory database. Is there any way to create `JdbcTemplate` bean without `DataSource`? Any how is this tutorial even work?

In pom.xml now I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but also tried with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

without success.

Comment: What do you think DataSource is? It **always** represent a database, may it be in memory or not. More on DataSource: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html

Another link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-embedded-database-java
You can see that embedded database is build and return **DataSource**. However, Spring Boot is smart enough and you don't see this code, however it does exactly the same as in the link. There is no magic.

Comment: with `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>` and `h2` in pom.xml I don't have to declare `@Bean JdbcTemplate` explicit.

Answer (score 2):

That is the beauty of `Spring-Boot`. It saw you are using `JdbcTemplate` so it need to create datasource and since you didn't provide any information, it is failing. Even though you are using in memory database you need to provide these info, so `spring-boot` can create `JdbcTemplate` for you. I am not sure which in memory db you are using, but here is an example on how to use with H2. You can find these info on individual dB user documentation.

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:yourdb`

`spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver`

`spring.datasource.username=`

`spring.datasource.password=`

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Comment: thanks for answer however in tutorial it works even without configuration file, they use h2 in memory database with `<scope>runtime</scope>`